# While practicing node.js, I was unable to install nodemon globally on windows. In cmd, it shows a version but in, vsc, it doesn't

Tags: node.js, backend, nodemon

[This image is the screenshot of vsc's terminal, it's showing errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmIns.png)

Comment: Copy the errors into here as text. And show us the commands you used

Comment: I have attached the errors in the image